# Chameleon Templating: Default value in 'tal:switch'

Tags: python, switch-statement, template-engine, chameleon

I am trying to build a switch/case structure around a range of integer values. As stated in the [language reference](http://chameleon.repoze.org/docs/latest/reference.html#tal-switch-and-tal-case), if the case expression is the symbol `default`, it always matches the switch. However, I am looking for a symbol that matches in all cases **except** for the ones listed above the symbol...

```
<ul tal:switch="i">
  <li tal:case="1">one</li>
  <li tal:case="2">two</li>
  <li tal:case="default">not one or two</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried the `otherwise` symbol, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True. There's no sense in the docs, because "default" will always match. It's a bug!

Please someone report it on the Github tracker.

Comment: This has now been fixed. Note that as a consequence, only a single ``tal:case`` can now succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain the symbol needs to be in the namespaced case statement or the parser will just ignore the symbol you put in there.

```
<ul tal:switch="i">
  <li tal:case="1">one</li>
  <li tal:case="2">two</li>
  <li tal:case="default">not one or two</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think that's the correct syntax. As I mess with it I can't seem to get default to work either for any sense of the term "default". This might just be a bug in Chameleon.